# Изменить размер массива

Tags: c, строки

В качестве учебного пособия я решил сделать консольный текстовый редактор.

Предполагаю хранить текст в массиве:

```
char *editor[0][0] = {}; //пока нету строк
```

Соответственно, при добавлении строки придется каждый раз создавать новый массив размером на 1 больше и перезаписывать данные туда.

**Вопрос: есть ли другой способ решения этого вопроса?**

Comment: Pure C? Но в С запрещается объявлять массивы размера `[0]`. И в С в принципе нет инициализатора `{}`.

Comment: Почему ваш массив указателей двумерен? Какую роль играет этот *двумерный* массив в вашем редакторе? Что за размеры вы собрались изменять и когда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вскидку, два возможных решения:

- Создавать массив с запасом. Обычное решение — удваивать размер при расширении.
- Использовать линейный список вместо массива.

Второе в данном случае ИМХО предпочтительнее.

Comment: линейные списки! то что надо, спасибо

Comment: @LeonidZolotarov, только учтите, что при работа со списками 1) сложнее; 2) медленнее